# ActiveStepChanged In CreateUserWizard

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am reading a [membership tutorial from ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/storing-additional-user-information-cs)

I am currently at the step titled:

> Customizing the CreateUserWizard’s Interface to Prompt for the New
>   User’s Home Town, Homepage, and Signature

What is supposed to happen is that I add a custom "step" to my CreateUserWizard, but when I run through this custom Step and hit "Continue", the values are NOT inserted into my Database, and if something is going wrong, then it should insert "NULL" into the database (as the tutorial tells, "if the user closes the registration during step 2, it will automatically insert NULL", but even that doesn't happen.

My database have 1 relation from `UserProfiles_Id to Aspnet_Users_UserId:`

```
FK_UserProfiles_aspnet_Users
```

I have gone through the steps in the tutorial serval times and I am still unable to find the problem.

Aspx.:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="NewUserWizard" runat="server" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/bruger/info.aspx">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep" runat="server">
        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="UserSettings" runat="server" StepType="Step" Title="Dine Informationer">
           <p>Navn:<br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" />
           </p>
           <p>Adresse:<br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="Adress" Columns="40" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" />
           </p>
           <p>Postnummer:<br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="ZipCode" Columns="20" Rows="5" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" />
           </p>
           <p>By:<br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="City" Columns="40" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" />
           </p>
        </asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server" >
        </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Aspx.cs:

```
 protected void NewUserWizard_ActiveStepChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Have we JUST reached the Complete step?
        if (NewUserWizard.ActiveStep.Title == "Complete")
        {
            WizardStep UserSettings = NewUserWizard.FindControl("UserSettings") as
            WizardStep;

            // Programmatically reference the TextBox controls
            TextBox Name = UserSettings.FindControl("Name") as TextBox;
            TextBox Adress = UserSettings.FindControl("Adress") as TextBox;
            TextBox ZipCode = UserSettings.FindControl("ZipCode") as TextBox;
            TextBox City = UserSettings.FindControl("City") as TextBox;

            // Update the UserProfiles record for this user
            // Get the UserId of the just-added user
            MembershipUser newUser = Membership.GetUser(NewUserWizard.UserName);
            Guid newUserId = (Guid)newUser.ProviderUserKey;

            // Insert a new record into UserProfiles
            string connectionString =
                 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LLCateringConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string updateSql = @"UPDATE UserProfiles SET Name = @Name, Adress = @Adress, ZipCode = @ZipCode, City = @City 
                               WHERE UserId = @UserId";

            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(updateSql, myConnection);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name.Text.Trim());
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adress", Adress.Text.Trim());
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipCode", ZipCode.Text.Trim());
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", City.Text.Trim());
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", newUserId);
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the line

```
if (NewUserWizard.ActiveStep.Title == "Complete")
```

to

```
if (NewUserWizard.ActiveStep == this.CompleteWizardStep1)
```

Comment: Still nothing happens. I checked the database to see if even the new UserID was added and it wasn't. It's supposed to take the UserId from aspnet_users and insert it into Userprofiles_UserId (eg. 637ea7d1-f2d1-40ca-b666-4fe0fbe7e86d)

Comment: It doesn't seem to fail anywhere from what I can find out.

Comment: Someone mentioned the following, but I still can't get it to work: "In the protected void NewUserWizard_ActiveStepChanged at the final part it is necessary to make an Insert instead of an update (string updateSql = "UPDATE ...) , so there is a little correction in the code."

Comment: Oh, if the user isnt present i the database, yes. Try something like: string updateSql = @"Insert into UserProfiles (UserId, Name, adress, zipcode, city) Values (ÂUserId, ÂName, ÂAdress, ÂZipcode, Âcity)"

Comment: The user is being created successfully in the aspnet_Users tabel. but I need to have the aspnet_users.UserId inserted/copied to UserProfiles.UserId. I do have a relation from UserProfiles_Id to Aspnet_Users_UserId.

Comment: And the above sql I just posted doesn't work? In that case, can you write out the newUserId and see if it matches the aspnet_users.UserId? If it does, the above insert-query should work!

Comment: You can see it in debugmode, or you can try to set the newUserId to a control on your page. Something like UserSettings.FindControl("Name").Text = newUserId; for example.